# Auto Scroll in div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I try to auto scroll this div but I'm stuck because I can't do what I want.
This snippet was retrieved from Stackoverflow and it should normally move horizontally. However my goal to make it vertically.

How do I do it?

```js
const flavoursContainer = document.getElementById('flavoursContainer');
const flavoursScrollHeight = flavoursContainer.scrollHeight;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  self.setInterval(() => {
    if (flavoursContainer.scrollTop !== flavoursScrollHeight) {
      flavoursContainer.scrollTo(flavoursContainer.scrollTop + 1, 0);
    }
  }, 15);
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="flavoursContainer">
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the second parameter of the `scrollTo(x, y)` method.

For example:

```
flavoursContainer.scrollTo(0, flavoursContainer.scrollTop + 1);
```